# Create an array variable for a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is a Javascript class that I have created.

```
(function(window){

    function Project(name,description){

    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;

    }

    window.Project = Project;


}(window));
```

I know to create variables inside the class using the 'this' keyword. But can someone help as how to create an array as member of the class. In this situation I need to create an array variable 'projectMemebers'

Comment: Are you sure about this. I mean when variables are created we use like this.name = name;  You sure something like that wont be needed

Comment: I'm quite sure, yes. The expression `[]` creates an empty Array instance.

Comment: @Pointy: +1 for adding this in comments....

Comment: I would have liked if you had answered the question. So I could have given the points to you. Who cares about points when you are 80k :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.projectMemebers = [];
```

or

```
this.projectMemebers = new Array();
```